# Checking if a set makes up a filter

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

> Definition: A non-empty family $\Lambda$ of subsets of a non-empty set $X$ is called
> a filter on $X$ if it satisfies the following three conditions:

> (i) $\emptyset \not \in  \Lambda$,

> (ii) $A, B \in \Lambda \implies  A \cap B \in \Lambda$,

> (iii) $(A \in \Lambda, A \subseteq S \subseteq X) \implies S \in \Lambda$.

---

- Consider $X = \{1, 2, 3\}$. Then $\Lambda = \{\{1\}, \{1, 2\}, \{1, 2, 3\}\}$ is a filter on $X$ because

  (i) $\emptyset \not \in \Lambda$

  (ii) $\{1\} \cap \{1, 2\}, \ \{1\} \cap \{1, 2, 3\}, \ \{1, 2\} \cap \{1, 2, 3\} \in \Lambda$

  (iii) $\{1\} \subseteq \{1\} \subseteq \{1, 2\} \subseteq \{1, 2, 3\} \subseteq \{1, 2, 3\} = X$, but $\{1\}, \{1, 2\}, \{1, 2, 3\} \in \Lambda$
- Let $\mathcal N(x)$ be the family of neighborhoods of a chosen point $x$ in a topological
  space $(X, \tau)$. Then  $\mathcal N(x)$ is a filter on $X$ because

  (i) $x \in N_i \in \mathcal N(x) \text{ for all $i$}  \implies \emptyset \not \in \mathcal N(x)$

  (ii) $x \in N_i \in \mathcal N(x) \text{ for all $i$} \implies x \in \bigcap N_i \implies \bigcap N_i$ is a neighborhood of $x$ and so $\bigcap N_i \in \mathcal N$

  (iii) $N_i \subseteq N_j \subseteq X \implies N_j \in \mathcal N(x)$ by definition
- $\{D_i\}_{i=1}^\infty (\subseteq \mathbb R)$ with $(-\infty, a] \subseteq D$ for some $a$ is a filter on $\mathbb R$ because

  (i) $(-\infty, a] \neq \{\} \implies D_i \neq \{\} \implies \{\} \not \in \{D_i\}_{i=1}^\infty $

  (ii) $(\infty, x] \cap (-\infty, y] = (\infty, x] \iff x < y$ and $(\infty, x] \cap (-\infty, y] = (\infty, y] \iff x \ge y$; either intersection is a subset of $D \in \{D_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$

  (iii) $D_1 \subseteq D_2\subseteq \mathbb R \implies D_2 \in \{D_i\}$ by definition
- $T = \tau_{cocountable} \setminus \{\emptyset\}$ is a filter on any uncountable set because

  (i) $\emptyset \not \in T$

  (ii) Suppose $A, B \in T$. Then $A^c, B^c$ are countable and so  $A^c \cup B^c = (A \cap B)^c$ is countable and so $A \cap B \in T$

  (iii) this criterion follows by definition

---

Are the proofs above convincing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have to consider the intersection of two sets. For the third you seem overly ambitious ( $\{D_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ ?). Just say

(ii): if $A,B$ are in the filter, for some $x,y \in \Bbb R$ we have $(-\infty,x] \subseteq A, (-\infty, y] \subseteq B$. Then

$$ (-\infty,x] \cap (-\infty,y] = (-\infty,\min(x,y)] \subseteq A \cap B$$

so that $A\cap B$ is in the filter too.

For the last, (iii) I would still mention that $A \subseteq B$ implies $B^\complement \subseteq A^\complement$ and that a subset of a countable set is still countable. Don't chicken out with "by definition" when it can easily be explained by a single line.

Where do you use the finiteness of the intersection in the second example? What's the relation with the topology?

Comment: In your last question, are you alluding to the fact that intersection of only finite number of open sets is open?

Comment: @user931361 indeed, that’s essential. It’s one of the reasons neighbourhoods and filters are so alike in structure.

Comment: You need more than a filter is closed under intersection, you also need that it is closed under superset (That's condition iii)

Comment: @Alan here that’s automatic from the definition ( a superset of..). We only need it’s a filterbase really.

Comment: If the choice of a's used in 3 aren't unbounded high,  it fails to be closed under superset.

Comment: @Alan that’s not true. That’s irrelevant.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma The $D_i$'s in the sequence aren't by default given to cover all of $\mathbb R$ by the way they are described

Comment: @Alan the definition is that $D$ is in the filter iff there is some $a$ with $(-\infty, a] \subseteq D$. This is clearly closed under supersets.

Answer (score 1):

All the ones except the third one looks good.  The third one requires an additional criteria that there is no upper bound on the chosen $a$'s that make up the $[-\infty,a]$ sets in your filter.  If there was an upper bound,  then you would no longer be closed under supersets, as adding things beyond that upper bound would no longer be in your filter

Comment: Is that part of the statement of the problem? If so, do I add anything to the proof?

Comment: @user931361 the third just requires us to be in a linearly ordered set, nothing more.